# Update query to update bulk records mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongodb version 3.2 and I need to update many records using single query.

My collection looks like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("573a2453e4b0882b6e286513"),
    "field1": "24333",
    "field2": "testfield"
}
```

Now I want to update field3 as true (Field3 is added now so it won't be there for older records).
So what will be the query for that and update suppose to happened in bulk
like I want to update records where field1="24333" or field2="3645" and field2="test1" or field2="test2" like that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there some specific issue that a plain [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) does not work for your case?

Comment: I was unable to make that query because when I tried it's giving syntax error.

Comment: can you update your question with the query that you used so we can have alook?